# assigning filename saved as variable with path info to another variable

Tags: php

I want to assign path info with filename, for which the file name is also stored in another variable, I'm using the following code but it is not working

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$ext = '.txt';
$counter_name = '/counters/titles/'.$title.$ext;
```

I want the counter_name variable to hold the path info and the file name, and then check if the file exist, if not, create a new one and initialize it to zero, this is working before I add the path info but now If when I checked the titles folder I can't see any .txt file there

```
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code. Do a `var_dump` of `$_POST` to make sure title is what you think it is.

Comment: I understand that, but the only problem that I can see lies in the fact that `$title` isn't what you think it is. Does `$counter_name` come out as `'/counters/titles/.txt'`?

Comment: @Grim let me modify the code, you can see what I want do

Comment: can you see full code now @Grim

Comment: Yup. None of that changes the fact that you need to know what `$title` is, and what `$counter_name` is. Just output them to the screen and see - it's debugging 101.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to and it now works

```
$title = $_POST['adtitle'];
$ext = '.txt';

if (!file_exists('counters/titles/'.$title.$ext)) {
  $f = fopen('counters/titles/'.$title.$ext, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
```